# Contact form on form submission redirects to index.twig

Tags: plugin-contactform

I've run into issues with the contact form plugin - https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/issues/156 - Any ideas

Comment: Have you checked where you're redirecting to? i.e. {{ redirectInput('contact/thanks') }}

Comment: Yeah, the redirect is set to '{{ redirectInput('thanks') }}'. This works fine in my local env, and redirects correctly.

Comment: Could you provide some code just incase there's something you might of missed? - Also which version of Craft are you running?

Comment: I've posted the code here: https://github.com/craftcms/contact-form/issues/156

Answer (score 1):

I inspected your form, and the redirect value is **45e4c422dc3ef7c10d24f04e10a42c07affd1f5456fb253747b332aed6481678thanks**.

Perhaps try being more explicit with your redirect, something like: `{{ redirectInput(siteUrl ~ 'thanks') }}`

Answer (score 0):

Responded to your Github issue, but my guess is you're getting a form validation error on submission and your template code isn't doing anything to display those errors.  You can see here for an example: https://github.com/craftcms/guest-entries#usage